# synchronized vs lock vs synchronized map

Tags: java, synchronization

I need to synchrozize my accesses to the hashmap.
Here are my options

1. I know I can use Synchronize keyword. this is one option. Can I use the map itself ?
2. currently I have a get method that   if the object does not exists creates it and puts it in the map. I can synchronize the method.
3. I can use a syncronize block
4. I can use
   Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap(...));
   in my code.

I tend to do 4 cause it sounds the easiest. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest that you *don't* make methods synchronized, and that you don't lock on the map itself. I generally prefer to use a separate locking object which is *only* used for locking and *only* known about in the class which owns the map.

You could *potentially* use `synchronizedMap`, but it depends what you want to do with it. If you only ever get and put values, then that's fine. If you ever need to *iterate* over the map, you need to block other threads from modifying the map while you're iterating.

Another option is to use a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). See the docs for the semantics. This is probably the simplest approach if it behaves the way you need it to.

Comment: Thanks . why not to use the map itself?

Comment: @useer450602: I like to know *exactly* what code might end up trying to acquire a lock - if I'm not in control of a lock, it makes it harder to reason about it. The only way to make sure that *no* other code can lock on something is to make it an object which only your code knows about to start with.

Answer (score 2):

You could use ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent() which may do what you want without synchronisation.